# Dialog component in primeNG no responsive on mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, angular, primefaces, primeng

I use primeNG (Angular2) to show the modal:

```
<p-dialog appendTo="body" [(visible)]="displayCreateGateway" modal]="true" [width]="700">
```

When I am on mobile view (less than declared 700px) modal does not display correctly. For example: I have window width 500 px, but modal generates in 700 px (properly will be width:100%). I think this is not fault of my code, because in official website primeNG situation is the same.

Do you know how to solve this problem? The easiest way is probably add media queries in css, but override component from primeNG isn't easy. Maybe helpful will be JS?

Comment: Please correct your tagging (read the content of all tags and remove those the one you are not using)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation of the component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog), you will see a `styleClass` attribute, used like this :

```
<p-dialog styleClass="myStyle">
```

When you do that, it adds a new class to the component, allowing you to style it as you want.

Comment: I import style (styleUrls:['custom.scss']) to this component.
So, I added style in this file and did like you said in HTML. Now, I see this class in browser inspector, but styles don't appear.

Comment: You see the class in HTML means it works. Now, it's a CSS related problem. You must inspect the dialog and see what causes the 700px width. Is it the `min-width` property ?

Comment: Even when I put style in HTML to this class doesn't work. 
It is inline style on this element `width:700px`.

Comment: I took me literally 5 seconds with an inspect on the primeNG website : `.myStyle .ui-dialog {width: 200px !important; }`

Comment: For me even this does not work. I see class in HTML but I don't see any style associated to this class.

Comment: Yes, I added styles in scss file and in HTML but I cannot see this in inspector.

Comment: Then add it in your global style files to see if it works

Comment: Still nothing. Maybe I can try do it with JS. I have no idea.

Comment: Well it works on my side, it should work on yours ... Let me test it

Comment: Tested and it works. You have to put your style into your global style file, and it gets applied to your component. Just inspect the dialog, see what in the component holds the width value (I did, it's `.ui-dialog`), and style it.

Comment: I add `.myStyle .ui-dialog{width:200px !important;}` to scss and global style. This is my html `<p-dialog appendTo="body" styleClass="myStyle" [(visible)]="displayCreateGateway" [draggable]="false" [modal]="true" [dismissableMask]="dismissableMask" [width]="700" [closeOnEscape]="closeOnEscape" [closable]="closable" [breakpoint]="700">`. 
And I see in HTML my class but without any styles.

Comment: Well it seems you can't achieve it. Anyway, in the documentation, you can see the `<p-dialog header="Title" [width]="300">`. So you can set your width with that.

Comment: In inspector: `<div class="myStyle ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow" ng-reflect-klass="myStyle" style="display: block; width: 700px; visibility: visible; left: 611px; top: 158px; z-index: 1001; opacity: 1;"`. 
And `.ui-dialog {position:fixed; padding:0}`.

Comment: I can declare width with `[width]="700"` but on mobile view after refresh it create like 700px width component. After resize browser it fixed to `width=100%`. But in first time is wrong.

Comment: Dude, I just made it. You don't give your max here. Please make some efforts. HTML : `<p-dialog header="Godfather I" visible="true" modal="modal" width="300" [responsive]="true" styleClass="MYCLASS"></p-dialog>` and CSS in the global file : `.MYCLASS {width: 900px !important;}`