# How to make a responsive MenuBar component of PRIMENG with grid system?

Tags: grid, responsive, primeng, menubar, primeflex

I am making a responsive web. I have problems with the MenuBar component of PrimeNG. I want to have the hamburger mode when i shrink the window:

[image: Hamburger]

The problem is using Grid System of PrimeFlex and putting the menu in a col-9, col-6 or anything that dont expand all the window. No responsive when shrinkink window:

[image]

There is any mode to have an hamburguer icon when the web shinks and reach border of the menu?

I try this and works:

```
min-width: 60em;
```

But no the smart thing to see in window and really no responsive. Also i cant put the menu in the top of the window, because is a sub-menu in a secondary window of the web.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842290/dialog-component-in-primeng-no-responsive-on-mobile-view#answer-44842351) explains you can use the styleClass attribute to achieve more complex styling behaviors ;)

here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77021159/keeping-primeng-p-menubar-to-stay-within-viewport/77022804#77022804).